# GIMP get Python dump

Tags: python, gimp

GIMP can interface with Python so that you can script operations.

But is there a way to perform a number of operations with the GUI toolboxes and see what the Python code necessary to do those operations would have been? That is, to record the scripting equivalent of your recent GIMP operations. [Paraview has a feature like this](http://www.paraview.org/python/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. There are no proper recording of actions performed in  GIMP code other than the undo system, and there are no hooks to introsect it via the plug-ins API, which Python uses.

This is a long time missing feature, that would need to be proper spec'ed, and written into code, and would require changes in several of places in the application - GIMP is a voluntary driven, developer starved project, so this probably won't be coming soon.

Finding non-interactivelly which PDB call performs a function however is relatively easy - I hope you've found the "browse" button on the interactive file console, which allows one to search through the PDB, and can paste a template call to each function on the console itself by using the `apply` button.

For the reference on a "macro-recorder": https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51937